# Embedding LinkedIn in Azure Single Page Application

Tags: single-page-application, linkedin-api

We are having an organizational level intranet portal. In which other than regular stuff we would like to integrate Social Media Posts/Wall/ Tweets. As part of that did the integration of Yammer, Twitter and Instagram (Via API's and Embedded)

Now when we trying to do the same for LinkedIn, we are ending up calling lot of API's for a single posts.

Would like seek any other alternatives to embedded the complete organization wall and it's posts (top 10 in the descending order of it's published) onto the single page application

Now when we trying to do the same for LinkedIn, we are ending up calling lot of API's for a single posts.